# How to Add and Use 'Numpy' Library?

Tags: numpy, intellij-idea

I would love to know how to run and add NumPy library after installation from the command prompt/ terminal in Intellij? I have successfully installed that one but it is not working properly. I need guidelines.

Thank You, Cheers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either [configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html) the interpreter to which you installed numpy (`where python` will probably show you the right one) in IntelliJ IDEA, or [install](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) numpy into your currently used interpreter.